# Crash with unwrapping a previously checked optional in a closure

Tags: swift, crash, closures

I have a very rare crash, probably involving a perfect timing (with closing the app or entering a background state?) The last line of this code

```
  fileprivate static func showNextDialog()
  {
    let next=futureDialogs.first
    if next != nil
    {
      futureDialogs.remove(next!)
      delay(0.01){showDialog(next!)}
    }
  }
```

results in a crash below

```
#0  (null) in Swift runtime failure: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value ()
#1  0x00000001049ff7ac in closure #1 in static InterfaceManager.showNextDialog() at ...
#2  (null) in partial apply for closure #1 in static InterfaceManager.showNextDialog() ()
```

The func delay is below:

```
func delay(_ delay:Double,_ closure:@escaping ()->())
{
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
    deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}
```

The only optional variable `next` was captured with let and checked for `nil`. Does anyone have ideas on what happens?

Comment: Maybe unrelated but why not merge the two lines for getting `next` and checking for nil into `if let next = futureDialogs.first {`?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `next`? It looks like it's a reference type, which means you don't capture it's value, but only address of the value.

While `showNextDialog` is waiting for `delay`, the value of `next` might change to `nil`. As a possible fix, you can check if it's `nil` a second time inside `delay`'s completion handler:

```swift
delay(0.01) {
  if let next {
    showDialog(next)
  }
}
```

P.S. A small related piece of advice: Avoid force-unwrapping and embrace the `guard let`/`if let` syntax instead of checking for equality to `nil`.

Comment: `static var futureDialogs=[UIViewController]()` so `next` is `UIViewController?`